# How to STOP getting an empty CSV file with Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When i run the code and i get my CSV file, its actually empty.

'''

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

url = 'https://www.fotocasa.es/es/alquiler/todas-las-casas/girona-provincia/todas-las-zonas/l'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
lists = soup.find_all('section', class_='re-CardPackAdvance')

with open('casas.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = writer(f)
    header = ['Titulo', 'Precio', 'Metros', 'Telefono']
    thewriter.writerow(header)
for list in lists:
    titulo = list.find('a', class_='re-CardPackAdvance-info-container').text.replace('\n', '')
    precio = list.find('span', class_='re-CardPrice').text.replace('\n', '')
    metros = list.find('span', class_='re-CardFeaturesWithIcons-feature-icon--surface').text.replace('\n', '')
    telefono = list.find('a', class_='re-CardContact-phone').text.replace('\n', '')
    info = [titulo, precio, metros, telefono]
    thewriter.writerow(info)
```

'''

I expected to have all the info scrapped from this website, but seems like i did something wrong at some point

Comment: find_all() is returning an empty list. Also, your *for* loop should be indented otherwise your output file will have been implicitly closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are parsing the resulting `soup` not appropriately. There is no `section` with the `re-CardPackAdvance` class. I adapted the code accordingly (find all `articles` with class that starts with `re-CardPack`). Please also note that you need to shift the `for`-loop by one indention. However, due to the structure of the page, only the first two entries are loaded directly when fetching the page. All other entries are fetched after the page has loaded in the browser (via javascript). I think you might consider using the API of the page instead.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer
import re

url = 'https://www.fotocasa.es/es/alquiler/todas-las-casas/girona-provincia/todas-las-zonas/l'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

lists = soup.find_all("article", class_=re.compile("^re-CardPack"))
print(len(lists))

with open('casas.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = writer(f)
    header = ['Titulo', 'Precio', 'Metros', 'Telefono']
    thewriter.writerow(header)

    for list in lists:
        titulo = list.find('a').get('title')
        precio = list.find('span', class_='re-CardPrice').text.replace('\n', '')
        metros = list.find('span', class_='re-CardFeaturesWithIcons-feature-icon--surface').text.replace('\n', '')
        telefono = list.find('a', class_='re-CardContact-phone').text.replace('\n', '')
        info = [titulo, precio, metros, telefono]
        thewriter.writerow(info)
```